# Searching for word in file and taking whole line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running this program to basically get the page source code of a website I put in. It saves it to a file and what I want is it to look for a specific string which is basically @ for the emails. However, I can't get it to work.

```
import requests
import re

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdKEdN66jUc&app=desktop'
data = requests.get(url)

# dump resulting text to file
with open("data6.txt", "w") as out_f:
    out_f.write(data.text)

with open("data6.txt", "r") as f:
    searchlines = f.readlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "@" in line:
        for l in searchlines[i:i+3]: print((l))
```

Comment: What doesn't work? If you get an error please share the traceback

Comment: You want the whole line or just the email?

Comment: i am just trying to find the email

Comment: i want to check if there is an email and if there is save that email to a file

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex method `findall` to find all email addresses in your text content, and use `file.read()` instead of `file.readlines()`. To get all content together rather than split into separate lines.

For example:

```py
import re

with open("data6.txt", "r") as file:
    content = file.read()

emails = re.findall(r"[\w\.]+@[\w\.]+", content)
```

Maybe cast to a set for uniqueness afterwards, and then save to a file however you like.

Comment: this is my code now and it worked but now i get an error.

code:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
    out_f.write(data.text)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\U0001f4b0' in position 636

Comment: @TechySavage that's coming from parts of you code that should not be changed based on the discussion we've had here, so it's hard to say exactly what the issue is without seeing the full code again and perhaps a sample of the input. I'd suggest marking this question as complete and asking a new question for this new error